# Why does this code run but still report a NonType object error?

Tags: python

I'm drawing a grid with the code as bellow (it's an exercise in Think Python btw). It looks horrible, but for the sake of debugging, it gives a NonType error despite still doing the job. Can you tell where I did wrong?

```
blank = " "
plus = "+"
minus = "-"
slash = "|"

def grid_kernel(f_p_m, f_s, f_b, p, m, b, s):
    f_p_m(p, m, b)
    f_b(b)
    f_s(s, b)
    f_b(b)
    f_s(s, b)
    f_b(b)
    f_s(s, b)
    f_b(b)
    f_s(s, b)
    f_b(b)
def print_grid(f_kernel, f_p_m, p, m, b, s):
    f_kernel(p, m, b, s)
    f_kernel(p, m, b, s)
    f_p_m(p, m, b)
def print_plus_minus(p, m, b):
    print(p, b, m, b, m, b, m, b, m, b, p, b, m, b, m, b, m, b, m, b, p)
def print_slash(s, b):
    print(s, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, s, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, s)
def print_blank(b):
    print(b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b)

print_grid(grid_kernel(print_plus_minus, print_slash, print_blank, plus, minus, blank, slash), print_plus_minus(plus, minus, blank), plus, minus, blank, slash)


+   -   -   -   -   +   -   -   -   -   +
                                         
|                   |                   |
                                         
|                   |                   |
                                         
|                   |                   |
                                         
|                   |                   |
                                         
+   -   -   -   -   +   -   -   -   -   +
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mypath/myfile.py", line 146, in <module>
    print_grid(grid_kernel(print_plus_minus, print_slash, print_blank, plus, minus, blank, slash), print_plus_minus(plus, minus, blank), plus, minus, blank, slash)
  File "/mypath/myfile.py", line 129, in print_grid
    f_kernel(p, m, b, s)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Firstly, none of your functions return anything, so the ```print_grid``` calls ```f_kernel``` which is the result from ```grid_kernel(...)``` but ```grid_kernel``` doesn't return any value (so defaults to ```None```)  So ```grid_kernel(..)``` becomes ```None(...)```  which is not valid.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean but I was trying Pythonanywhere, so maybe it looks bit different. But I don't withhold information, except for shortening/masking the path and file name, which still I think doesn't matter too much in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the function `grid_kernel`, which does stuff and returns `None`, then you pass that `None` as the first argument of `print_grid`, which tries to call it. Thus the `NoneType is not callable`.